# Regex extract string based on pattern

Tags: asp.net, regex

See below string we have in document

```
    32Main Section
    32.1Assignment and transfers by Obligors
    32.2Additional Borrowers
    (a)Subject to compliance with the provisions of paragraphs (c) and (d) of Clause 28.10 ("Know your customer" checks),
```

Output Expected (List string only if they have this xx.xx pattern at the start of the line)

```
32.1Assignment and transfers by Obligors
32.2Additional Borrowers
```

Regex we are trying `\d+(\.\d{1,2}.*)`

But this gives us 3rd line also which we dont have as it has number in the middle of line. We want to list only lines which start with the number or decimal...

Comment: Use `^`, `^\d+\.\d{1,2}.*`

Comment: You can try this `^\d+\.\d+.*\n`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - how to modify this further that at start it could be number or decimal (so it could be 10 or 10.2 and after that is text)

Comment: I think it will be `^\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?.*` or just `^\d.*`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - can you add this as answer pls - ^\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?.* - this worked for me

Comment: It occurs to me that it might not be really a good solution. The `(?:\.\d{1,2})?` is an optional pattern, and since you are using `.*` after it, it means you do not even need that one. Just `^\d.*` will do then. Else, you need to specify a delimiter for the number. Say, `^\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?[ .].*`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `^\d.*` this is really neat. cheers mate :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew but it will than match `23.abc` and also `32Main` . is it desirable op ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to match any string starting with a digit, so `^\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?.*` that can be shortened to `^\d.*` will do the job.

A better idea is to specify a delimiter for the number. Say,

```
^\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?[ .].*
                  ^^^^
```

Or make sure there is no digit:

```
^\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?(?!\d).*
                  ^^^^^^
```

The `[ .]` will require a space or `.` after the initial number.

**Details**

- `^` - start of a string
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `(?:\.\d{1,2})?` - an optional non-capturing group

  - `\.` - a dot
  - `\d{1,2}` - 1 or 2 digits
- `[ .]` - a space or `.`
- `.*` - the rest of the string.

Comment: is it possible to add space between number and when words start... like "43.1 Agreement" using REGEX

Comment: @user3657339 Yes, `Regex.Replace(s, @"^(\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?)(?![\d\s])(.*)", "$1 $2")`

Comment: @user3657339 Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this mate**

```
^\d+\.\d+.*
```

> Explanation

- `^` - Anchor to start of string.
- `\d+\.\d+` - Matches `xx.xx` pattern (x is number).
- `.*` - Matches anything except newline. zero or more time (greedy mode)

[Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5cd%2b%5c.%5cd%2b.*&i=32.1Assignment+and+transfers+by+Obligors%0d%0a32.2Additional+Borrowers%0d%0a%28a%29Subject+to+compliance+with+the+provisions+of+paragraphs+%28c%29+and+%28d%29+of+Clause+28.10+%28%22Know+your+customer%22+checks%29&o=m)